# How to get the JSON part of an HTML document in Android

Tags: android, html, json

I want to parse a JSON script in Android Studio where I have to **get the JSON script** which is a part **of an HTML document** and not the HTML part.There are other JSON scripts in the HTML document but I have to **use specifically this part/script** Here is the sample of the HTML document I have to use...
(The HTML document is the source code of a webpage not owned by me)

```
                            ...........other HTML parts
</script><script type="application/ld+json">
    [                       ...........start of the JSON part
     {
      "@context":"http://schema.org",
       "@type":"Event",
            ...             ...........other JSON data
         "name": "EasyLearning Tre"
        }
       ] 
     }
    ]                       ...........end of the JSON part
  </script><div class="eh-carousel-header row">
                            ...........other HTML parts
```

I have downloaded the whole HTML Document using ASyncTask and now I want to get the JSON part of this document. Here is what I've tried...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText urlContents;
String content=null;
Button navigate;
StringBuilder sb;

    public void navigate(View v){

         DownloadContents downloadContents = new DownloadContents();

         try{
             navigate.setText("Downloading...");content=downloadContents.execute("https://www.eventshigh.com/bangalore/technology?src=home").get();
         }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    public class DownloadContents extends AsyncTask<String,Void ,String> {

        String result="";
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                String line = null;

                while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                in.close();


                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.toString();

            }
        }

       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            navigate.setText("Downloaded...");          

            String[] splitResult= result.split("</script><script type=\"application/ld+json\">");

            String[] nextSplitResult=splitResult[1].split("<script><div class=\"eh-carousel-header row\">");
            String mainResult=nextSplitResult[0];
            urlContents.setText(mainResult);


        }
    }
}
```

But what I figured out is that the split function is not splitting the document.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Thank you @FluffyKitten for the suggestion. I'll try my best next time. However, I had done something which I added recently. Hope it informs you a bit more.

Comment: WHy are you embedding it in html?  Don't do that-  you're just making your life harder.  Make it a separate endpoint.

Comment: @GabeSechan actually that HTML document is a source code of the URL mentioned in the Android code (the webpage is not owned by me). I want to get only that JSON part of the HTML Document.

Comment: @RickV is it isn't owned by you and they don't want to make it public, find another way to get the data. Depending on a screen scraped is questionably legal and will break at a moment's notice with no ability for you to control it. It basically should never be done

Comment: @GabeSechan thank you for the advice.. I'll try to find a different way. Can you please suggest me any api which will provide me the list of technical events and their details happening or going to happen based on cities or countries. I tried to find such api from every possible source but couldn't find any.. So i thought of scrapping this data from the webpage.

Comment: If you must do this, you're better off using JSoup or something to parse the HTML: https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-parse-html-pages-on-android-with-jsoup-2a9b0da0096f

Comment: Thank you @nasch this worked for me.